# flutter_quill: ^7.4.6 Error: No named parameter with the name 'onLiveTextInput'

Tags: flutter, rich-text-editor

I want to use flutter_quill: ^7.4.6 for my Flutter app

This is my homework description widget:

[image]

And I called this widget in my form widget like this:

[image]

But when I run the project, it will give this error:

```
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onLiveTextInput'.
raw_editor.dart:353
      onLiveTextInput: null,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:1832:38: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static List<ContextMenuButtonItem> getEditableButtonItems({`
```

This is the full error code inside the console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onLiveTextInput'.
      onLiveTextInput: null,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:1832:38: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static List<ContextMenuButtonItem> getEditableButtonItems({

                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\FlutterDev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\FlutterDev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried to add this in a separate Scaffold widget, but it is not working.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77094340/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue is described in *[Major bug on Android #1384](https://github.com/singerdmx/flutter-quill/issues/1384)*.

From what I understand from the discussion there, you need to either downgrade flutter_quill to 7.2.0 or 7.3.0 or you need to upgrade Flutter to 3.13 or higher.

Answer (score -1):

The error arises from the fact that `EditableText.getEditableButtonItems()` does not have an `onLiveTextInput` parameter. Because the SDK can be directly modified, unlike in other languages, you can comment out line 364 in `src/widgets/raw_editor/raw_editor.dart`:

```dart
// lines 0–360
List<ContextMenuButtonItem> get contextMenuButtonItems {
  return EditableText.getEditableButtonItems(
    clipboardStatus: _clipboardStatus.value,
    // onLiveTextInput: null,
    onCopy: copyEnabled
        ? () => copySelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar)
        : null,
// line 368 onwards
```

Comment: I think the rest of the answer might've been cut off....

Comment: Sorry, my description was not clear enough and has been modified.